# Issue on third INNER/LEFT join and count mismatch

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query which gives me certain fields like JOB_TYPE, WORK_SUBTYPE & JOB_TYPE. I have a reference tables which contains description for these three columns. I need to lookup for these three columns in the reference table and my output should provide me three new columns providing the description for the same.

Given below is the query. My concern is when i do a join, the output provides me "Null" as well as "actual description" for Work_Type_Description : This line in code - "left join [dbo].[REF_table] t3 on t3.[Work Type] = A.WORKTYPE ". Instead of 14 rows, i get 28 rows and my sum function shows around 36 instead of 1. Can someone help me fix this? I'm clueless what the issue could be.

```
select  WORKORDERNO
       ,LOCATION
       ,WORKTYPE
       ,t3.[Work Type Description] as WORK_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
       ,WORK_SUBTYPE
       ,t2.[Sub Type Description] as SUB_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
       ,JOB_TYPE
       ,t.[Budget Process Description] AS PROCESS_NAME
       ,PROJECT_NUMBER
       ,SUM(ISNULL(CAST(COMPANYCOUNT AS INT),0)) AS COMPANY
       ,SUM(ISNULL(CAST(CONTRACTORCOUNT AS INT),0)) AS CONTRACTOR 

FROM
(SELECT WORKORDERNO
      ,STATUS
      ,cast(STATUSDATE AS DATE) AS ACT_FINISH
      ,WORKTYPE
      ,WORK_SUBTYPE
      ,LOCATION
      ,concat(WORKTYPE,WORK_SUBTYPE) as JOB_TYPE
      ,ASSIGNED_LABOR
      ,CASE WHEN [ASSIGNED_LABOR] IN ('X','Y','Z') THEN '1' ELSE '0'
                                      END AS COMPANYCOUNT
      ,CASE WHEN [ASSIGNED_LABOR] IN ('X','Y','Z') THEN '0' ELSE '1'
                                      END AS CONTRACTORCOUNT
      ,SUBSTRING(ACCOUNT, CHARINDEX('-', ACCOUNT, charindex('-', ACCOUNT, CHARINDEX('-', ACCOUNT, CHARINDEX('-', ACCOUNT,  
                CHARINDEX('-', ACCOUNT) +1 ) +1) +1) +1) +1, 13) AS PROJECT_NUMBER 
     ,FIELD_REMARKS
FROM [TTT].[dbo].[Current _Status] 
WHERE STATUS in ('COMP', 'FDCOMP', 'EBCOMP', 'EBERROR', 'FLN', 'FDCPERR')) A
left join [dbo].[REF_table] t on t.[Job Type] = A.JOB_TYPE
left join [dbo].[REF_table] t2 on t2.[Sub Type] = A.WORK_SUBTYPE 
left join [dbo].[REF_table] t3 on t3.[Work Type] = A.WORKTYPE 
where ACT_FINISH between '2018-04-30' and '2018-06-01' and LOCATION = 'ABC' AND WORKTYPE = 'C' 
and field_remarks is not null   
and t3.[Work Type Description] is not null
GROUP BY
      a.WONUM
     ,A.LOCATION
     ,a.WORKTYPE
     ,A.WORK_SUBTYPE
     ,A.JOB_TYPE
     ,t.[Budget Process Description]
     ,t2.[Sub Type Description]
     ,t3.[Work Type Description]
     ,PROJECT_NUMBER
   order by
        PROCESS_NAME
```

To remove the duplicates, i  added this this to where clause and it fixed my issue. "and t3.[Work Type Description] is not null". My main concern is the count that its providing.

Ref table looks like this:
[image]

I figured out that its showing me the count of "Worktype" rows in the reference table. Worktype category that i filtered is 36 in count in that column. How do i fix this issue?

pls help.

Comment: You have two entries for each `WorkType` in your `Ref_Table`. One that is NULL and that contains the Description that you are after. You could add to `ON t3.[Work Type] = A.WORKTYPE` with `AND t3.[Work Type Description] IS NOT NULL` instead of doing that in your WHERE clause. Those values will be suppressed BEFORE the join which should make your query perform faster. The really odd thing though is this `Ref Table` it sounds like maybe it should be three tables, one for each type `Job_Type`, `Work_Subtype` and `Worktype`.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what `REF_table` looks like. @JNevill's supposition about three tables perhaps being more appropriate is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Edited my Question to add how my Ref_table looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in answering this but I just saw that you updated the question with the structure of your `REF_table`. Here are what I think are the relevant parts of your query:

```
select  
    [...]
   ,t3.[Work Type Description] as WORK_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
   ,t2.[Sub Type Description] as SUB_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
   ,t.[Budget Process Description] AS PROCESS_NAME
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            [...]
            ,concat(WORKTYPE,WORK_SUBTYPE) as JOB_TYPE
            [...]
        FROM [TTT].[dbo].[Current _Status] 
        WHERE STATUS in ('COMP', 'FDCOMP', 'EBCOMP', 'EBERROR', 'FLN', 'FDCPERR')
    ) A
    left join [dbo].[REF_table] t on t.[Job Type] = A.JOB_TYPE
    left join [dbo].[REF_table] t2 on t2.[Sub Type] = A.WORK_SUBTYPE 
    left join [dbo].[REF_table] t3 on t3.[Work Type] = A.WORKTYPE 
    [...]
```

In the subquery `A` you are constructing a `JOB_TYPE` code which is a concatenation of the `WORKTYPE` and `WORK_SUBTYPE` codes. But then you're joining to `REF_table` three times using each of `JOB_TYPE`, `WORK_SUBTYPE`, and `WORKTYPE` as a predicate. This might make sense *if* all three of those values were independent of one another, and if you were sure that `REF_table` contained at most one record for any given value of any one of those fields. But they're not independent: because `JOB_TYPE` is a function of `WORKTYPE` and `WORK_SUBTYPE`,  a record in `REF_table` that has a certain `JOB_TYPE` code will also have information on the `WORKTYPE` and `WORK_SUBTYPE` that compose that `JOB_TYPE`. So you don't need three joins to the table; you only need one, like so:

```
select  
    [...]
   ,t.[Work Type Description] as WORK_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
   -- References to t2 and t3 replaced with references to t
   ,t.[Sub Type Description] as SUB_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
   ,t.[Budget Process Description] AS PROCESS_NAME
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            [...]
            ,concat(WORKTYPE,WORK_SUBTYPE) as JOB_TYPE
            [...]
        FROM [TTT].[dbo].[Current _Status] 
        WHERE STATUS in ('COMP', 'FDCOMP', 'EBCOMP', 'EBERROR', 'FLN', 'FDCPERR')
    ) A
    left join [dbo].[REF_table] t on t.[Job Type] = A.JOB_TYPE
    -- t2 and t3 joins removed
    [...]
```

I think JNevill might still have a point about the design of `REF_table`: it seems somewhat redundant, in that if you have a `WORKTYPE` that can be combined with 10 different `WORK_SUBTYPE` codes, your current data model requires that you store the `[Work Type Description]` 10 different times. If that description can legitimately *vary* depending on the `WORK_SUBTYPE`, then the existing structure makes sense, but if a single `WORKTYPE` code should always have the same description regardless of which `WORK_SUBTYPE` it's paired with, then storing it multiple times is both wasteful and prone to data integrity issues. (In other words, if `REF_table` ends up storing multiple descriptions for the same `WORKTYPE` code on different records, how do you know which description is the correct one?)

It's certainly possible that you can't change the data model, or that you don't want to for whatever reason—that's totally understandable. In that case I'd simply use the query changes that I recommended above. I just thought this was worth pointing out.